# Is there a javascript method to find out if a string is part of another string?

Tags: javascript

I need to find out if one string is in another and return true or false, or something similar.

just remembered having read something about indexof returning something like -1 if it doesn't find something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function of String:

```
var str = "something";
var other = "thi";
if (str.indexOf(other) != -1) {
    // other is a part of the original string.
}
```